# How would I overlay a scatter plot on a mirrored bar chart in Highcharts?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts, bar-chart, scatter-plot

I'm trying to add a scatter plot to a mirrored bar chart in Highcharts. I'm using React, but the Highcharts config is just vanilla JS.

I'm trying to put the scatter plot markers at the end of the bars. I have two scatter series, one for each side of the mirror. However, only the second series seems to map correctly (image attached).

[image: Bad chart]

The code I'm using to achieve this is

```
import React from "react";
import * as Highcharts from "highcharts";
import HighchartsReact from "highcharts-react-official";

const MirroredBarChart = () => {
  const data = [[-10, -50], [50, 10]];

  const series = [
    {
      color: "coral",
      data: data[0],
      stack: "X"
    },
    {
      color: "turquoise",
      data: data[1],
      stack: "X"
    },
    {
      type: "scatter",
      data: data[0],
      stack: "X",
      color: "black",
      marker: {
        symbol: "circle"
      }
    },
    {
      type: "scatter",
      data: data[1],
      stack: "X",
      color: "black",
      marker: {
        symbol: "diamond"
      }
    }
  ];

  const options = {
    chart: {
      type: "bar"
    },
    plotOptions: {
      series: {
        stacking: "normal"
      }
    },
    series
  };

  return <HighchartsReact highcharts={Highcharts} options={options} />;
};

export default MirroredBarChart;
```

One weird thing is that if I switch the scatter plot series items around in the array, it's always the last one that plots correctly.

Am I doing something stupid? Anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That issue is caused by `stacking`, which creates a separate stack for negative values in `column` and `bar` series. As a solution, you can set stacking only for `bar` series:

```
plotOptions: {
    bar: {
        stacking: "normal"
    }
}
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/Ld0hjybv/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.stacking